# How can I set role based access control in Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using fire base ,and I want to separate admin and users and I want that admin should be directed to specific activity and user directed to other.
How can I perform this.
I have tried in Auth method but it doesn't work.

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    progBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Admin.class))
    } else {

    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question how you distinguish between admin and non-admin users.  You're going to have to figure out how to do that before you can write any effective code.

Comment: Thats what am figuring out that how to distinguish between admin and non-admin.

Comment: Firebase Authentication doesn't have a built-in concept of admin users. If you need this, you will have to build it on top of Firebase yourself.

Comment: My impression is that it's common to use custom claims in Firebase Auth to mark users with admin privileges. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Yup, typically you mark admins with a custom claim in their profile, since being an admin is a relatively stable state (where you can deal with the propagation delay). Other group memberships are typically handled by storing them in a database (Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database).

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication doesn't have a built-in concept of admin users. If you need this, you will have to build it on top of Firebase yourself.

A typical way to do this would be to add a [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to a user's profile when that user is an admin. You can do this with the Firebase Admin SDK with something as simple as:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true})
```

But note that this the Admin SDK is only to be used in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions. Otherwise, anyone could mark themselves as admin of your app with the above code.

With the custom claim in place, you [client can read that claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client) (it takes up to an hour to propagate to the clients), and show the correct UI based on that.

Comment: i want to redirect admin to specific activity where admin will add or remove other users data.and normal users should directed to other activity.

Comment: The above approach will allow you to do that. Check the link about reading the claim on the client for sample code.